# Can simple-oauth2 support multiple oauth transactions simultaneously?

Tags: simple-oauth2

I want to use simple-oauth2 in a node.js application to facilitate login to my service.  Do I need to instantiate an instance for each user that is actively logging in ( using oauth2module.create() ) or can I reuse a single global instance for multiple logins that are going on at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally it appear a single simple-oauth2 instance can be used to service multiple simultaneous oauth transactions.